# ElasticSearch Snapshot across cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

Recently I created a `snapshot` of an index in an `elasticsearch` cluster consisting of 3 data nodes.

My main purpose is to move this index in another cluster.

Commands I used:

```
PUT /_snapshot/my_backup

{
    "type": "fs",
    "settings": {
        "location": "/home/me/backup",
        "compress": true
    }
}


PUT _snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=true
{
  "indices": "daily-20141127"
}
```

Note: Above queries were executed in the same data node.

`Snapshot` was successfully created in the above location but **in another node from where I hit the queries** and each node in this backup location had a folder(name:indices) which contained the shards of backup index on equivalent node.

Example:
node1: home/me/my_backup/indices/1,2,3
node2: home/me/my_backup/indices/4,5,6
node3: home/me/my_backup/indices/7,8,9

So I had to manually copy all indices folders across cluster to the node which had the metadata of snapshot to complete backup. I then copied backup folder to new cluster and restored it(restore procedure was fine)

Can all indices folders of backup index be in 1 node instead of being split across cluster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `location` you are specifying should be a "shared" location and the path specified in the repository should point to the same directory shared across all nodes. It cannot be just a local directory on the node. For example: that location can be a network-shared mount on a separate machine and all nodes should point to it and should be able to access it.

The reason for this is that each node may hold a primary or a replica from a shard and it should be able to make a copy of the docs contained in that specific shard and then moved over to the "shared" location.

Comment: I know it's been a while but I'm wonder why this also holds true for localhost. I'm running into a problem where ES claims that it can't create the file. The error kept claiming that it "doesn't match any of the locations specified by path.repo because this setting is empty", yet my elasticsearch.yml definitely has the path

Comment: @JChao do you have the path specified on each node?

Comment: hey I got this one solved. Problem was due to my being stupid and typed path.repo as path,repo......

Answer (score 1):

As Andrei wrote - to use snapshots over multiple nodes, you will need a shared location which can be accessed by all nodes and you have to elasticsearch.yml settings with identical path.repo entry.

There is a guide how to [create shared repositories across multiple clusters](https://medium.com/@botond.kopacz_84714/getting-started-with-elasticsearch-installation-ecf44d06e7fe) which covers all the steps you need, including setting up Samba server and clients  + configuring ElasticSearch.